# How to convert this Google Spreadsheet's menu to Google Docs

Tags: menu, google-apps-script, google-docs

This works in Google Spreadsheet:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menu = [ 
{name: "Initialize", functionName: "labnolReset"},
{name: "Test", functionName: "test"}
];  
  ss.addMenu("Gmail", menu);
  ss.toast("Please click the GMail menu above to continue..", "", 5);
}
```

How to convert it to Google Docs? I tried to copy the code into Google Doc, then assign `ss` with `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()`, but it didn't work. I get neither the GMail menu nor the "toast".

I also tried:

```
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu("Gmail", menu).addToUi();
```

but that didn't work either.

please help.

Comment: The answer below is perfect (and I voted it up btw) but if you had made use of the autocomplete feature available in gas script editor you wouldn't even had to ask your question because you would have seen the answer while typing the code... DocumentApp.getUi() followed by a single dot and you see every possible methods available instantly :-)  very useful feature for lazy people like me ^^

Comment: Do I have to do anything special to made use of the autocomplete feature available in gas script editor? I'm using chromium-browser from latest Ubuntu (saucy), but it doesn't work for me. E.g., DocumentApp.getUi() followed by a single dot and I don't see anything pop up.

Comment: normally it is control space to activate... you can see it the edit menu : content assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed have menu's in Google Docs.  You have to understand that the implementation of scripts started with Sheets and evolved to touch very many other areas of Google Apps.  In that respect the implementation for Docs is quite different.

The best place to lear about Google Apps Script is to peruse the excellent documentation found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

And in the specific case of your query the link to read up is here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#custom_menus_and_user_interfaces

For menu's this is the specific code you can use

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sample Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Custom UIs')
          .addItem('Show HTML dialog', 'showDialog')
          .addItem('Show HTML sidebar', 'showSidebar'))
      .addToUi();
}
```

The toast is specific to spreadsheets, not available in docs.  On the other hand you will be able to use these: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String)

Comment: Thank your Patrick. The insight of evolvement/differences between the two menu systems is even more helpful than the solution itself to me.